# Making similar functions prettier?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

So I have an sequence which calls different function which do similar things and have the same signature.

```
{
  if(!calcFunc1(sameTypeA, sameTypeB)
    || !calcFunc2(sameTypeB, sameTypeC)
    || !calcFunc3(sameTypeB, sameTypeD)
    || !calcFunc4(sameTypeC, sameTypeE)
    // more ...
    )
  {
    // some error handling
  }
}
```

With the sginature

```
bool calcFunc1(const MyClass& classInput, MyClass& classOutput) const;
bool calcFunc2(const MyClass& classInput, MyClass& classOutput) const;
bool calcFunc3(const MyClass& classInput, MyClass& classOutput) const;
// more ...
```

These functions are doing similar things but differently. So overall I have different algorithms which work on the data package over and over again (every algo make the data more "precise" with his own technique, so I get each time a smaller subset). These function are normal and nothing special about it.

Theoretically the output is always the input of the next, but it does not have to be, but I do not know if I need this special case (see input of calcFunc2 and calcFunc3). If this special case would make your solution less elegant, then leave it out.

So my question is, can I make this more elegant/clean? I use at least c++11, not sure if I can use c++17. Library support can only be std or boost.

If these would be classes, I would think about polymorphism, so I wonder if there is something similar to it for functions. Or maybe i should use an interface (abstract class), but I am unsure. I am open for any suggestion.

Example: Lets say MyClass is an image and I want to extract some letter. Then each calcFunc tries to extract the letter.
sameType is the maskedImage (Region of Interest). They get additionaly a copy of the unprocessed image of the beginning, so they can work on this and the result from the  previous algorithm, but this is not important for the idea.
The idea is, that the algorithms are more conservative and tries not to be aggressive with their extraction, so they do not lose some important data (like they could filter out some line of the letter). My idea is, that each calcFunc work softly on the data and just cut out obvious parts (this is why I sayed "subsets").
Also my idea is, that the future programmer could add his own calcFunc and do it differently, change the order or add more functions which could work differently on the data.
For example calcFunc5 could make the Region of Interest in the masked Image again bolder, so a missing ending of lines could be again in the image. And calcFunc6 filters again data which are not wanted, like the surrounding of the missed line which calcFunc5 added.

Sorry I am not very good in english and hope you can understand my problem.

Comment: _"These functions are doing similar things but differently"_ - So, they are just like normal functions then? Perhaps you should look at [ranges-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) for a nice way to write filtering chains.

Comment: yes they are normal functions. Nothing special about. Sorry can not add any special library besides std and boost.

Comment: Good question. Yes they have to be non-static, because they use some member variables. For more background: They are implemented in an inner struct from a class (PIMPL idiom).

Comment: Sorry, I removed my question if they need to be non-`static` member functions, because I noticed it's not as much of an issue (more of a nuisance and having to choose some other solutions). Do you need to keep intermediate states? As is, it seems you have multiple `MyClass` variables, each storing output of a different call.

Comment: Perhaps you can make a [mre] to demonstrate what it is you are doing right now so it's easier to see if it can be made prettier. If it's working code, you may also consider asking at [codereview](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778)

Comment: They do not have to keep intermediate states. Its really not so complicated, but good question. They work like a pipeline, while having a lot of similiarites (signature and what their goal is).

Comment: Seems like a good case for `optional` (either Boost or std) with monadic interface. IIRC Sy Brand has implemented sth like that, see [here](https://github.com/TartanLlama/optional). If you're limited to boost/std only there should not be too much problems in implementing it yourself either. I would probably wrap the original functions and then chain and_then followed by or_else, but that's just my personal preference.

Comment: Do I take the 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', ... pattern in our output parameters literally? Does each call get a unique output object? Since the object is using pimpl pattern, you are not worried about the cost of the default constructor, so you are okay with them being references to objects?

Comment: If you want a future programmer to write their own `calcFunc`s then they can't be member functions (unless you're happy for your class to be modified every time a new function is added).  A way to avoid that is to specify your pipeline as a collection of `std::function<bool (const MyClass &, MyClass &)>`  (which is an object that can wrap a raw function, a member function (along with an object it acts on), etc etc).  Then your sequencing can be done by a function that iterates over the collection of functions, and all future programmers need to worry about is constructing that collection.

Comment: @kazikoni _"I updated my question :)"_ - Can you please show your code too? Include a few minimal `calcFunc`s  tooso that it's clear how they are to be used. We should preferably be able to compile your program.

Answer (score 0):

You could "simplify" by using Boolean algebra:

```
bool result = CalcFunc1(/*...*/);
result = result && CalcFunction2(/*...*/);
result = result && CalcFunction3(/*...*/);
//...
```

The above is an *example* of using a Boolean technique.  It may not answer the OP's question and the logic may need to be changed.

Print out the assembly language for your original function, then print out the assembly language for the above code.  Compare and discuss.